# Wrapping text around a box in the corner but keep scroll possibility

Tags: html, css

I have some text which should wrap around a toolbox in the top right corner.
The total height should be limited, therefore the text should be scroll-able.

The corner box should stay in the corner, not scrolling with the text.

How can I achieve this?

I have a box and some text, but when adding `overflow-y: scroll` it will break like this:

```css
.box {
  width: 100px;
  height: 40px;
  float: right;
  clear: both;
}

#blue {
  background-color: blue;
}

#text {
  height: 120px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

```html
<div id='blue' class='box'></div>
<div id='text'>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
  in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit,
  sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore
  eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
</div>
```

Comment: you will have a bad scrolling experience if the text need to move around the box while scrolling

Comment: Do you want the text to go around the box when scrolling or is it OK that it scrolls under the box (as in @ibrahimHamaty answer)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add a div as a parent for the box and text and set the blue box position to sticky `position: sticky;`

I hope This is what you want

```css
.box {
    width:100px;
    height:40px;
    float:right;
    clear: both;
}

#blue {
    background-color:blue;
    position: sticky;
    top: 0;
}

#text {
}
.container{
 height: 120px;
    overflow-y: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
 <div id='blue' class='box'></div>
  <div id='text'>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
  </div>
</div>
```